# Compairing tuple with numpy array element tuple

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, error-handling, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to compare the NumPy array (cd) elements which are in form of tuples with (0,0):

```
print(cd)
[[( 34,  34) ( 85,  34) (137,  34) (  0,   0) (240,  34) (292,  34)]
[( 34,  85) (  0,   0) (137,  85) (  0,   0) (240,  85) (291,  85)]
[( 34, 137) ( 85, 137) (137, 137) (188, 137) (240, 137) (291, 137)]
[(  0,   0) ( 86, 191) (137, 188) (188, 188) (  0,   0) (291, 188)]
[( 34, 240) ( 85, 240) (137, 240) (  0,   0) (  0,   0) (291, 240)]
[( 34, 292) (  0,   0) (137, 291) (188, 291) (240, 291) (  0,   0)]]

def topological_array():
    topo_arr=np.zeros((6,6))
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(6):
            if (cd[i][j]!=(0,0)):
                topo_arr[i][j]=1
            else:
                topo_arr[i][j]=0
```

On executing the function `topological_array()`, I am getting this warning:

```
topo_arr=topological_array()

<ipython-input-67-8a4e228ddd9d>:5: FutureWarning: elementwise != comparison failed and 
returning scalar instead; this will raise an error or perform elementwise comparison in the 
future.
```

The Numpy version is 1.20.1 and the python version is 3.8. I am not able to get the `topo_arr`
due to this warning. How can I resolve this?
Please resolve this issue.
Thank you!

**Edit: datatype of cd is: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])**

Comment: What's `cd.dtype`?  By the way, that's a **warning** not an error.

Comment: @hpaulj,  I have initialised 'cd' like this: cd=np.zeros((6,6),dtype='i,i').

Comment: So the array is not an array of tuples. You might be able test it against a 0d array of the same `dtype`.  I'd have to test that.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want an array with 1s and 0s compared with (0,0).

I think this might work.

```
topo_arr = (cd == np.zeros((6,6),dtype='i,i')) * 1
```

**Edit:**

Function :

```
def topological_array(arr):
    topo_arr = (arr == np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype='i,i')) * 1
    return topo_arr 

topo = topological_array(cd)
print(topo)
```